# Continual "transport close" on client

Tags: socket.io

I've setup socket.io v.1.4.5 w express and I have been unable to trace the reason for unexplainable disconnects on the clients. The reason given by the disconnect event on the client is "transport close." It happens very consistently on some clients.

Is there any explanation for a client getting "transport close" disconnects on what seems to be a timed interval? The client reconnects just fine but it causes extreme inconvenience because it happens so frequently.

I've tried various settings, like changing the pingInterval, pingTimeout and the port for websockets (I am now using port 80). But no matter what I seem to do, the problem never goes away.

Comment: upgraded to the latest socket.io and still having the problem. turned off windows firewall, still having the problem. seems to only happen on one of my PCs.

Comment: So, a socket.io connection on the client is not closed on the client end unless it is deemed to be non-functional (lack of heartbeats) or if someone tells the client to close the connection or of the server closed the other end of the connection.  So, if your connection is getting closed and nobody is telling it to close, then it must be concluding that it is non-functional in which case it would try to reconnect.  Does your client try to reconnect?  If so, what happens when it does?  Your server should be able to deal with a reconnect just fine.

Comment: If your server can't handle the reconnect, then you need to make a few changes to your server so that it works just fine after a reconnect.  If you are getting a lot of reconnects, then you have some sort of transport problem, probably an issue with long running socket connections.  A common suspect in that type of symptom is an uncooperative firewall or a misconfigured proxy or perhaps even overly assertive anti-virus software.

Comment: my server can handle the reconnect just fine, problem is it interrupts the user experience in a major way.

Comment: Exactly how long from initial connection until the socket closes and then reconnects?  Does that time period change if you change the timing configuration of the server and client heartbeats?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in an extremely small sample app where both client and server are on the same host and there is no other code involved except a socket.io connection?  Can you reproduce the problem when client and server are both node.js apps on the same host?

Comment: it's definitely sporadic, but when it does happen, it seems to happen on a timed interval, like every 20 seconds or so. But sometimes it won't happen at all. It's entirely unpredictable!